# Calling JavaScript function that is inside a function from html

Tags: javascript, html, function

Struggling a bit with nested functions. Problem, I want to call a function from my HTML, but all my JavaScript sits inside to wait for the DOM loaded function.

If I take the function I want to call out of the DOM loaded function, I can not access the variables from inside the DOM loaded function.

Comment: Can you share your code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably when you say you "call a function from [your] HTML" you mean:

```
<div onclick="yourFunction()">...</div>
```

...or similar.

This is one of the many reasons not to use `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers: You can only call your own functions if they're globals.

Instead, hook up the handlers with modern event handling techniques, such as `addEventListener`. If you do that, you can use any function in-scope of your code doing the hookup, it doesn't need to be a global anymore.

Simple example:

```js
(function() {
  // Not global
  function fooClick() {
    console.log(".foo clicked");
  }
  
  // Hook it up
  document.querySelector(".foo").addEventListener("click", fooClick);
})();
```

```html
<div class="foo">Click me</div>
```