# DOMContentLoaded seems to break my script?

Tags: javascript, html

So I was trying to make a really basic script, when someone clicks on a button some text would appear. The problem is that if I use document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded') and put the script in it, then I get this error:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick")

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
 function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("B");
    var t = document.createTextNode("Some bold text");
    x.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(x);
}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Click the button to create a B element with some text.</p>

 <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

 <script src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

^This doesn't work.
If I change the JS to:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("B");
    var t = document.createTextNode("Some bold text");
    x.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(x);
}
```

it does. Can you explain to me what's happening? I can't really get it.

Comment: Is `myFunction()` within `js.js`?

Comment: Why did you put your function inside DOMContentLoaded?

Comment: Literally [just answered this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48488553/calling-javascript-function-that-is-inside-a-function-from-html). Don't use `onxyz`-attribute event handlers. They can only call global functions.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder then how should my code look? Can you correct it?

Comment: @Musa as far as I know, that's good practice. I shouldn't do it with everything I think, though.

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu: Did you read my answer to the linked question? Which has an example?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes. I did now. Thanks!

Comment: If `myFunction` is defined in `js.js` you can place `<script src="js.js"></script>` before `<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>` within the HTML